# SwiftyCam capture session is not running

Tags: swift, avcapturesession, swiftycam

I have created my camera view following the demo project on GitHub from [SwiftyCam](http://github.com/Awalz/SwiftyCam) Everything lays out correctly and is going well; however, when the camera button is pushed I get a message in the console saying "[SwiftyCam]: Cannot take photo. Capture session is not running". There have been other people having this problem with swift 4 and you can find that [here](http://github.com/Awalz/SwiftyCam/issues/117). I have gone through the whole framework line by line but for some reason I can't figure it out. I would really appreciate it if someone could look at the framework and the documentation and help me out. The way I'm doing it is just about exactly how it's done in the Swift 4 [demo project](http://github.com/Awalz/SwiftyCam/tree/Swift4/DemoSwiftyCam/DemoSwiftyCam) so that would be the code reference.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: Below is the code when setting up the SwipeNavigationController after the WelcomeVC

```
let swipeNavigationController = SwipeNavigationController(centerViewController: CameraViewController())

    swipeNavigationController.topViewController = BlueView()
    swipeNavigationController.bottomViewController = PinkView()
    swipeNavigationController.leftViewController = OrangeView()
    swipeNavigationController.rightViewController = GreenView()



    cameraView.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)


    orangeView.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

    greenView.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)





    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: swipeNavigationController)

    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Below is all the code in the CameraVC

```
    class CameraViewController: SwiftyCamViewController, SwiftyCamViewControllerDelegate, SwipeNavigationControllerDelegate {




    let orangeVC = OrangeView()

    let greenVC = GreenView()
    let blueVC = BlueView()
    let pinkVC = PinkView()



    let flipCameraButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        let image = UIImage(named: "cameraSwitch")
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cameraSwitchTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    let captureButton: SwiftyRecordButton = {
        let button = SwiftyRecordButton(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 572, width: 75, height: 75))
        //let image = UIImage(named: "focus")
        //button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        //button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cameraTapped), for: .touchUpInside)




        return button
    }()



    let orangeButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        let image = UIImage(named: "OrangeIcon")
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToOrange), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    let greenButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        let image = UIImage(named: "GreenIcon")
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToGreen), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    let pinkButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        let image = UIImage(named: "pinkCameraIcon")
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToPink), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(flipCameraButton)
        view.addSubview(captureButton)
        view.addSubview(orangeButton)
        view.addSubview(greenButton)
        view.addSubview(pinkButton)

        shouldPrompToAppSettings = true
        cameraDelegate = self
        maximumVideoDuration = 10.0
        shouldUseDeviceOrientation = true
        allowAutoRotate = true
        audioEnabled = true


        // disable capture button until session starts
        captureButton.buttonEnabled = false

        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
            navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

        setupViews()

    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        captureButton.delegate = self

    }


    //


    @objc func goToOrange() {


        orangeVC.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

        self.containerSwipeNavigationController?.showEmbeddedView(position: .left)
    }

    @objc func goToGreen() {


        greenVC.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

        self.containerSwipeNavigationController?.showEmbeddedView(position: .right)


    }

    @objc func goToPink() {


        self.containerSwipeNavigationController?.showEmbeddedView(position: .bottom)
    }

    @objc func cameraSwitchTapped() {
        switchCamera()
    }

    @objc func cameraTapped() {
        print("CAMERA TAPPED")

        takePhoto()
    }




    func setupViews() {

        flipCameraButton.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 25, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 12, width: 35, height: 35)

        captureButton.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: pinkButton.topAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 10, paddingRight: 0, width: 75, height: 75)
       captureButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        orangeButton.anchor(top: nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 10, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 75, height: 75)

        greenButton.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 10, width: 75, height: 75)

        pinkButton.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: -10, paddingRight: 0, width: 75, height: 75)
        pinkButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        view.addSubview(flipCameraButton)
        view.addSubview(captureButton)
        view.addSubview(orangeButton)
        view.addSubview(greenButton)
        view.addSubview(pinkButton)
    }



    //MARK: Camera Protocols

    func swiftyCamSessionDidStartRunning(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController) {
        print("Session did start running")
        captureButton.buttonEnabled = true
    }

    func swiftyCamSessionDidStopRunning(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController) {
        print("Session did stop running")
        captureButton.buttonEnabled = false
    }


    func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didTake photo: UIImage) {
        let newVC = AfterPhotoTakenView(image: photo)
        self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didBeginRecordingVideo camera: SwiftyCamViewController.CameraSelection) {
        print("Did Begin Recording")
        captureButton.growButton()
        hideButtons()
    }

    func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didFinishRecordingVideo camera: SwiftyCamViewController.CameraSelection) {
        print("Did finish Recording")
        captureButton.shrinkButton()
        showButtons()
    }

    func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didFinishProcessVideoAt url: URL) {
        let newVC = VideoView(videoURL: url)
        self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didFocusAtPoint point: CGPoint) {
        print("Did focus at point: \(point)")
        focusAnimationAt(point)
    }

    func swiftyCamDidFailToConfigure(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController) {
        let message = NSLocalizedString("Unable to capture media", comment: "Alert message when something goes wrong during capture session configuration")
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "AVCam", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Alert OK button"), style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didChangeZoomLevel zoom: CGFloat) {
        print("Zoom level did change. Level: \(zoom)")
        print(zoom)
    }

    func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didSwitchCameras camera: SwiftyCamViewController.CameraSelection) {
        print("Camera did change to \(camera.rawValue)")
        print(camera)
    }

    func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didFailToRecordVideo error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }








    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }


}




extension CameraViewController {

    fileprivate func hideButtons() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {

            self.flipCameraButton.alpha = 0.0
        }
    }

    fileprivate func showButtons() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {

            self.flipCameraButton.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }

    fileprivate func focusAnimationAt(_ point: CGPoint) {
        let focusView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "focus"))
        focusView.center = point
        focusView.alpha = 0.0
        view.addSubview(focusView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            focusView.alpha = 1.0
            focusView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.25, y: 1.25)
        }) { (success) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                focusView.alpha = 0.0
                focusView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
            }) { (success) in
                focusView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func toggleFlashAnimation() {
        if flashEnabled == true {
            //flashButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flash"), for: UIControlState())
        } else {
            //flashButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flashOutline"), for: UIControlState())
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like when a user swipes to another view, as well as the buttons aren't responsive and the user can't swipe up or down for those views either.

[image]

Here is an example of a view I'm trying to present when the user swipes from left to right or clicks the pink messages button.

```
class MessagesView: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    setupNavBar()

    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        setupNavBar()
    } else {
        setupNavBar()
    }
}

func setupNavBar() {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Messages"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.pinkNeonColor
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
}
```

}

Comment: if you run demo project on your device, is it working or not?

Comment: @shivi_shub yes it does. I'm not sure what it is because I'm doing the exact same thing as in the demo

Comment: you are installing through pods?

Comment: @shivi_shub originally yes, but I just uninstalled it and used the source folder from the demo project and I am still getting the same result

Comment: I am not sure if it's because I have it on a SwipeNavigationController (framework with views similar to Snapchat)

Comment: on swipe navigation where are you using swiftly cam? center or any other?

Comment: @shivi_shub I’m using the center for the camera

Comment: can you send the code because it is woking fine in my project

Comment: @shivi_shub I have just added all the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public enum Position {
case center
case top
case bottom
case left
case right
}

enum ActivePanDirection {
case undefined
case horizontal
case vertical
}


public protocol SwipeNavigationControllerDelegate: class {

func swipeNavigationController(_ controller: SwipeNavigationController, willShowEmbeddedViewForPosition position: Position)

func swipeNavigationController(_ controller: SwipeNavigationController, didShowEmbeddedViewForPosition position: Position)
}

open class SwipeNavigationController: SwiftyCamViewController, SwiftyCamViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet fileprivate var currentXOffset: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet fileprivate var currentYOffset: NSLayoutConstraint!

open fileprivate(set) weak var activeViewController: UIViewController!

public weak var delegate: SwipeNavigationControllerDelegate?

open fileprivate(set) var centerViewController: UIViewController!

open var topViewController: UIViewController? {
    willSet(newValue) {
        self.shouldShowTopViewController = newValue != nil
        guard let viewController = newValue else {

            return
        }
        addEmbeddedViewController(viewController, previousViewController: topViewController, position: .top)
    }
}
open var bottomViewController: UIViewController? {
    willSet(newValue) {
        self.shouldShowBottomViewController = newValue != nil
        guard let viewController = newValue else {
            return
        }
        addEmbeddedViewController(viewController, previousViewController: bottomViewController, position: .bottom)
    }
}
open var leftViewController: UIViewController? {
    willSet(newValue) {
        self.shouldShowLeftViewController = newValue != nil
        guard let viewController = newValue else {
            return
        }
        addEmbeddedViewController(viewController, previousViewController: leftViewController, position: .left)
    }
}
open var rightViewController: UIViewController? {
    willSet(newValue) {
        self.shouldShowRightViewController = newValue != nil
        guard let viewController = newValue else {
            return
        }
        addEmbeddedViewController(viewController, previousViewController: rightViewController, position: .right)
    }
}

open override var shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods: Bool {
    get {
        return false
    }
}

@IBOutlet fileprivate var mainPanGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
fileprivate var previousNonZeroDirectionChange = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
fileprivate var activePanDirection = ActivePanDirection.undefined
fileprivate let verticalSnapThresholdFraction: CGFloat = 0.15
fileprivate let horizontalSnapThresholdFraction: CGFloat = 0.15

fileprivate var centerContainerOffset: CGVector!
fileprivate var topContainerOffset: CGVector!
fileprivate var bottomContainerOffset: CGVector!
fileprivate var leftContainerOffset: CGVector!
fileprivate var rightContainerOffset: CGVector!

open var shouldShowTopViewController = true
open var shouldShowBottomViewController = true
open var shouldShowLeftViewController = true
open var shouldShowRightViewController = true
open var shouldShowCenterViewController = true

fileprivate let swipeAnimateDuration = 0.2

public init(centerViewController: UIViewController) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    shouldShowTopViewController = false
    shouldShowBottomViewController = false
    shouldShowLeftViewController = false
    shouldShowRightViewController = false
    self.centerViewController = centerViewController
    addChildViewController(centerViewController)
    centerViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}


public func swiftyCamSessionDidStartRunning(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController) {
    print("Session did start running")
    captureButton.buttonEnabled = true
}

public func swiftyCamSessionDidStopRunning(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController) {
    print("Session did stop running")
    captureButton.buttonEnabled = false
}

public func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didTake photo: UIImage) {
    let newVC = PhotoViewController(image: photo)
    self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

public func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didBeginRecordingVideo camera: SwiftyCamViewController.CameraSelection) {
        print("Did Begin Recording")
        captureButton.growButton()
        hideButtons()
    }

public func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didFinishRecordingVideo camera: SwiftyCamViewController.CameraSelection) {
        print("Did finish Recording")
        captureButton.shrinkButton()
        showButtons()
    }

public func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didFinishProcessVideoAt url: URL) {
        let newVC = VideoViewController(videoURL: url)
        self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

public func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didFocusAtPoint point: CGPoint) {
        print("Did focus at point: \(point)")
        focusAnimationAt(point)
    }

public func swiftyCamDidFailToConfigure(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController) {
    let message = NSLocalizedString("Unable to capture media", comment: "Alert message when something goes wrong during capture session configuration")
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "AVCam", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Alert OK button"), style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

public func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didChangeZoomLevel zoom: CGFloat) {
    print("Zoom level did change. Level: \(zoom)")
    print(zoom)
}

public func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didSwitchCameras camera: SwiftyCamViewController.CameraSelection) {
    print("Camera did change to \(camera.rawValue)")
    print(camera)
}

public func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didFailToRecordVideo error: Error) {
    print(error)
}
public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

let flipCameraButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    let image = UIImage(named: "cameraSwitch")
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cameraSwitchTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()

let captureButton: SwiftyRecordButton = {
    let button = SwiftyRecordButton(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 572, width: 75, height: 75))
    let image = UIImage(named: "focus")
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cameraTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

let orangeButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    let image = UIImage(named: "OrangeIcon")
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToOrange), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()

let greenButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    let image = UIImage(named: "GreenIcon")
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToGreen), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()

let pinkButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    let image = UIImage(named: "pinkCameraIcon")
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToPink), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()

@objc func goToOrange() {
    //orangeVC.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    self.containerSwipeNavigationController?.showEmbeddedView(position: .left)
}

@objc func goToGreen() {
    //greenVC.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    self.containerSwipeNavigationController?.showEmbeddedView(position: .right)
}

@objc func goToPink() {
    self.containerSwipeNavigationController?.showEmbeddedView(position: .bottom)
}

@objc func cameraSwitchTapped() {
    switchCamera()
}

@objc func cameraTapped() {
    print("CAMERA TAPPED")

    takePhoto()
}

// Mark: - Functions
open override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.cameraDelegate = self

    if currentXOffset == nil && currentYOffset == nil {
        view.addSubview(centerViewController.view)
        centerViewController.view.isHidden = true
        centerViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.currentXOffset = alignCenterXConstraint(forItem: centerViewController.view, toItem: view, position: .center)
        self.currentYOffset = alignCenterYConstraint(forItem: centerViewController.view, toItem: view, position: .center)
        view.addConstraints([self.currentXOffset, self.currentYOffset])
        view.addConstraints(sizeConstraints(forItem: centerViewController.view, toItem: view))
    }

    testViewdid()
    assert(currentXOffset != nil && currentYOffset != nil, "both currentXOffset and currentYOffset must be set")

    if mainPanGesture == nil {
        mainPanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onPanGestureTriggered(sender:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(mainPanGesture)
    }


    let frameWidth = view.frame.size.width
    let frameHeight = view.frame.size.height
    centerContainerOffset = CGVector(dx: currentXOffset.constant, dy: currentYOffset.constant)
    topContainerOffset = CGVector(dx: centerContainerOffset.dx, dy: centerContainerOffset.dy + frameHeight)
    bottomContainerOffset = CGVector(dx: centerContainerOffset.dx, dy: centerContainerOffset.dy - frameHeight)
    leftContainerOffset = CGVector(dx: centerContainerOffset.dx + frameWidth, dy: centerContainerOffset.dy)
    rightContainerOffset = CGVector(dx: centerContainerOffset.dx - frameWidth, dy: centerContainerOffset.dy)
    activeViewController = centerViewController
}

open override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    activeViewController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: animated)

}

open override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    activeViewController.endAppearanceTransition()
    captureButton.delegate = self

}

open override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    activeViewController.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: animated)
}

open override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    activeViewController.endAppearanceTransition()
}

func testViewdid() {
    view.addSubview(flipCameraButton)
    view.addSubview(captureButton)
    view.addSubview(orangeButton)
    view.addSubview(greenButton)
    view.addSubview(pinkButton)

    shouldPrompToAppSettings = true
    cameraDelegate = self
    maximumVideoDuration = 10.0
    shouldUseDeviceOrientation = true
    allowAutoRotate = true
    audioEnabled = true
    captureButton.buttonEnabled = true

    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    //setupViews()
}

// Let UIKit handle rotation forwarding calls
open override func shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods() -> Bool {
    return true
}

// MARK: - Containers
open func showEmbeddedView(position: Position) {
    weak var disappearingViewController: UIViewController?
    let targetOffset: CGVector

    switch position {
    case .center:

        if !activeViewController.isEqual(centerViewController) {
            disappearingViewController = activeViewController
        }
        activeViewController = centerViewController
        targetOffset = centerContainerOffset
    case .top:
        activeViewController = topViewController
        targetOffset = topContainerOffset
    case .bottom:
        activeViewController = bottomViewController
        targetOffset = bottomContainerOffset
    case .left:
        activeViewController = leftViewController
        targetOffset = leftContainerOffset
    case .right:
        activeViewController = rightViewController
        targetOffset = rightContainerOffset
    }

    if !activeViewController.isEqual(centerViewController) {
        disappearingViewController = centerViewController
    }

    currentXOffset.constant = targetOffset.dx
    currentYOffset.constant = targetOffset.dy
    disappearingViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: true)
    activeViewController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
    delegate?.swipeNavigationController(self, willShowEmbeddedViewForPosition: position)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: swipeAnimateDuration, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (finished) in
        self.delegate?.swipeNavigationController(self, didShowEmbeddedViewForPosition: position)
        self.activeViewController.endAppearanceTransition()
        disappearingViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
    }
}

open func isContainerActive(position: Position) -> Bool {
    let targetOffset: CGVector
    switch position {
    case .center:
        targetOffset = centerContainerOffset
    case .top:
        targetOffset = topContainerOffset
    case .bottom:
        targetOffset = bottomContainerOffset
    case .left:
        targetOffset = leftContainerOffset
    case .right:
        targetOffset = rightContainerOffset
    }
    return (currentXOffset.constant, currentYOffset.constant) == (targetOffset.dx, targetOffset.dy)
}


open func lock() {
    self.mainPanGesture.isEnabled = false
}
open func unlock() {
    self.mainPanGesture.isEnabled = true
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return true
}

@IBAction fileprivate func onPanGestureTriggered(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .began:

        if isContainerActive(position: .top) || isContainerActive(position: .bottom) {
            activePanDirection = .vertical
        } else if isContainerActive(position: .left) || isContainerActive(position: .right) {
            activePanDirection = .horizontal
        } else {
            activePanDirection = .undefined
        }

    case .changed:

        let translationInMainView = sender.translation(in: view)

        if translationInMainView.x != 0 {
            previousNonZeroDirectionChange.dx = translationInMainView.x
        }

        if translationInMainView.y != 0 {
            previousNonZeroDirectionChange.dy = translationInMainView.y
        }

        switch activePanDirection {
        case .undefined:
            activePanDirection = fabs(translationInMainView.x) > fabs(translationInMainView.y) ? .horizontal : .vertical

        case .horizontal:

            let isCurrentlyShowingRightViewController = currentXOffset.constant < centerContainerOffset.dx
            let isCurrentlyShowingLeftViewController = currentXOffset.constant > centerContainerOffset.dx
            let minX = isCurrentlyShowingRightViewController || shouldShowRightViewController ? rightContainerOffset.dx : centerContainerOffset.dx
            let maxX = isCurrentlyShowingLeftViewController || shouldShowLeftViewController ? leftContainerOffset.dx : centerContainerOffset.dx

            if shouldShowCenterViewController {
                currentXOffset.constant = min(max(minX, currentXOffset.constant + translationInMainView.x), maxX)
            }
        case .vertical:

            let isCurrentlyShowingBottomViewController = currentYOffset.constant < centerContainerOffset.dy
            let isCurrentlyShowingTopViewController = currentYOffset.constant > centerContainerOffset.dy
            let minY = isCurrentlyShowingBottomViewController || shouldShowBottomViewController ? bottomContainerOffset.dy : centerContainerOffset.dy
            let maxY = isCurrentlyShowingTopViewController || shouldShowTopViewController ? topContainerOffset.dy : centerContainerOffset.dy

            if shouldShowCenterViewController {
                currentYOffset.constant = min(max(minY, currentYOffset.constant + translationInMainView.y), maxY)
            }
        }

        // reset translation for next iteration
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)

    case .ended:
        /*
         * Handle snapping here
         */
        switch activePanDirection {
        case .horizontal:

            if currentXOffset.constant > 0.0 {

                // within range of center container
                if currentXOffset.constant < (horizontalSnapThresholdFraction * view.frame.size.width) {
                    showEmbeddedView(position: .center)
                }

                    // within range of left container
                else if currentXOffset.constant > ((1.0 - horizontalSnapThresholdFraction) * view.frame.size.width) {
                    showEmbeddedView(position: .left)
                }

                    // center region: depends on inertia direction
                else {
                    // pulled right
                    if previousNonZeroDirectionChange.dx > 0.0 {
                        showEmbeddedView(position: .left)
                    }

                        // pulled left
                    else {
                        showEmbeddedView(position: .center)
                    }
                }
            }

            else if currentXOffset.constant < 0.0 {

                // within range of center container
                if currentXOffset.constant > (horizontalSnapThresholdFraction * -view.frame.size.width) {
                    showEmbeddedView(position: .center)
                }

                    // within range of right container
                else if currentXOffset.constant < ((1.0 - horizontalSnapThresholdFraction) * -view.frame.size.width) {
                    showEmbeddedView(position: .right)
                }

                    // center region: depends on inertia direction
                else {
                    // pulled left
                    if previousNonZeroDirectionChange.dx < 0.0 {
                        showEmbeddedView(position: .right)
                    }

                        // pulled right
                    else {
                        showEmbeddedView(position: .center)
                    }
                }
            }

        case .vertical:
            if currentYOffset.constant > 0.0 {

                if currentYOffset.constant < (verticalSnapThresholdFraction * view.frame.size.height) {
                    showEmbeddedView(position: .center)
                }

                else if currentYOffset.constant > ((1.0 - verticalSnapThresholdFraction) * view.frame.size.height) {
                    showEmbeddedView(position: .top)
                }
                else {

                    if previousNonZeroDirectionChange.dy > 0.0 {
                        showEmbeddedView(position: .top)
                    }

                    else {
                        showEmbeddedView(position: .center)
                    }
                }
            }

            else if currentYOffset.constant < 0.0 {

                if currentYOffset.constant > (verticalSnapThresholdFraction * -view.frame.size.height) {
                    showEmbeddedView(position: .center)
                }

                else if currentYOffset.constant < ((1.0 - verticalSnapThresholdFraction) * -view.frame.size.height) {
                    showEmbeddedView(position: .bottom)
                }
                else {

                    if previousNonZeroDirectionChange.dy < 0.0 {

                        showEmbeddedView(position: .bottom)
                    }

                    else {
                        showEmbeddedView(position: .center)
                    }
                }
            }

        case .undefined:
            break
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}

func addEmbeddedViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, previousViewController: UIViewController?, position: Position) {
    if viewController.isEqual(previousViewController) {
        return
    }
    previousViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: false)
    previousViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
    previousViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
    previousViewController?.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    previousViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()

    addChildViewController(viewController)
    view.addSubview(viewController.view)
    view.sendSubview(toBack: viewController.view)
    viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    view.addConstraint(alignCenterXConstraint(forItem: viewController.view, toItem: centerViewController.view, position: position))
    view.addConstraint(alignCenterYConstraint(forItem: viewController.view, toItem: centerViewController.view, position: position))
    view.addConstraints(sizeConstraints(forItem: viewController.view, toItem: centerViewController.view))
}

func alignCenterXConstraint(forItem item: UIView, toItem: UIView, position: Position) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
    let offset = position == .left ? -self.view.frame.width : position == .right ? toItem.frame.width : 0
    return NSLayoutConstraint(item: item, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: toItem, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: offset)
}

func alignCenterYConstraint(forItem item: UIView, toItem: UIView, position: Position) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
    let offset = position == .top ? -self.view.frame.height : position == .bottom ? toItem.frame.height : 0
    return NSLayoutConstraint(item: item, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: toItem, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: offset)
}

func sizeConstraints(forItem item: UIView, toItem: UIView) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: item, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: toItem, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: item, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: toItem, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    return [widthConstraint, heightConstraint]
}
func hideButtons() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {

        self.flipCameraButton.alpha = 0.0
    }
}

 func showButtons() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {

        self.flipCameraButton.alpha = 1.0
    }
}

 func focusAnimationAt(_ point: CGPoint) {
    let focusView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "focus"))
    focusView.center = point
    focusView.alpha = 0.0
    view.addSubview(focusView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        focusView.alpha = 1.0
        focusView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.25, y: 1.25)
    }) { (success) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            focusView.alpha = 0.0
            focusView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
        }) { (success) in
            focusView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}

 func toggleFlashAnimation() {
    if flashEnabled == true {
        //flashButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flash"), for: UIControlState())
    } else {
        //flashButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flashOutline"), for: UIControlState())
    }
}
}
```

CameraViewControler -

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

}
}
```

Comment: That makes sense thank you. I am not sure how to change it to SwiftyCamViewController like you said. I can't import SwiftyCam into SwipeNavigationController

Comment: @Jaqueline i am able to use SwiftyCamViewController without any hassle. I am using without pods. You just need to replace UIViewController with SwiftyCamViewController, SwiftyCamViewControllerDelegate.

Comment: have you actually replaced it? I'm using the SwiftyCam without pods but the SwipeNavigationController with pods, should I use that one without pods as well? The error I get when replacing UIViewController for SwiftyCamViewController and SwiftyCamViewControllerDelegate are "use of undeclared type 'SwiftyCameViewController' ", also the same message for the delegate

Comment: please check if you copied swiftcam source folder correctly

Comment: Yes I copied it straight from github and it was working previously (without the buttons working just able to see the preview). Where you able to add the SwiftyCamViewController into the SwipeNavigationController? The SwipeNavigationController is a pod are you also using it as a pod? maybe something has to happen with the Targets that you changed? I'm not sure

Comment: No in my case SwipeNavigationController is not a pod. I am using it directly. Because I need to change SwipeNavigationController class.

Comment: Ok so I was able to add SwipeNavigationController directly and modify the class to add the view controller and delegate; however, it's not working as expected and I don't think it's correct with the protocol stubs and everything. Would you mind adding the code of how you did it to your answer? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: You just need to write all the code and protocols of CameraViewController into SwipeNavigationViewController. One thing that I forgot to share is Remove all the code from CameraViewController as it will become the centerviewcontroller. And also hide the centerviewcontroller.view in viewdidLoad of SwipeNavigationVieController

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not working correctly at all for me, and I know that I'm doing this all wrong. Would you mind sharing the code?

Comment: Check edited answer. removed comments because of exceed length of post box

Comment: thank you so much for that! I am now able to take photo and the session is running. The only thing that needs to be fixed is when you swipe to go to another view controller (like OrangeView) it provides the navigation bar on top of basically the camera view instead of presenting a table view. How may I go about this?

Comment: sorry. question is not clear. can you attach the image or anything?

Comment: Yes I just added a screenshot. So what happens is when I swipe to go to another view from the camera view, it will only show the navigation bar, and not load the whole view like it should. and the transition isn't a swipe, as well as, you can't swipe up or down for the other views.

Comment: It is happening because swiftycam zooms in and out on swipe gesture. Can you provide the code for orange view or any other view that you are presenting

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Ok I just added the code. Also in the SwiftyCamViewController I disabled the pan gesture so that it will work on the SwipeNavigation Controller; however, it won't present the top and bottom views, as well as, the buttons won't take the user to that view

Comment: I change the code and added it to git. I use the storyboard this time. You can download and check. Thanks---  https://github.com/shubhamrajgit/SwipeSwiftyExample

Comment: Thank you! I will do it tomorrow and get back to you since it’s pretty late here

Comment: have you checked?

Comment: So I did what you did in the storyboard after your GitHub but nothing was working correctly but I’m going to look at it again this week. I’m traveling right now but I will get back to you after I look at it again

Comment: After looking back nothing was workign correctly and I was getting crashes left and right, so rather than using SwiftyCam's framework I decided to make my own Camera based off of the ideas of their framework, and everything works perfectly. However since it worked great on your end I will mark the answer correct. Thank you for all your help!