# UINavigationBar not loading correctly

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I know there are a lot of questions out there on this topic; however, none of those answers have helped me and I have tried so many ways of going about solving this. My problem is that my bar button will not show up, originaly, but when the viewcontroller is presented later on in the app it will show up then but the navigation title won't show up. I'm not sure why that is, but I believe it has something to do with the SwipeNavigationController framework that I'm using. My goal is to have the button show up as it's supposed to when the user swipes left to get to that view, and also when the view is later called and presented to look the same. The code for adding the navItem is below:

```
let cameraBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cameraIcon"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goToCamera))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cameraBarButton
```

Please look at this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688217/swiftycam-capture-session-is-not-running) to get a little better understanding of the framework. As well as here is the code on how I set up the navigation bar:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupView()

    let barHeight: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
    let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
    let displayHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height

    messagesTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: barHeight, width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight - barHeight))
    messagesTableView.register(BlankCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: blankCellID)
    messagesTableView.dataSource = self
    messagesTableView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(messagesTableView)

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    setupNavButtons()
    setupNavBar()

   showNoMessagesLabel()



    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {



    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        setupNavBar()
    } else {
        setupNavBar()
    }
}

func setupNavBar() {



    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Messages"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.pinkNeonColor
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white


}

func setupNavButtons() {
    let cameraButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    cameraButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cameraIcon").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    cameraButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cameraButton)
}
```

Comment: **where**  is the `let cameraBarButton......` written? Try placing it inside `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` and see if it works

Comment: That's where it is but it's very odd because when I swipe slowly I can see it how it should be, but once I swipe all the way, it's not there like it's been hidden behind or something

Comment: @Jaqueline Could you please add more of your code to make your question clearer?

Comment: @Carpsen90 I have just added more of the code, please take a loot at it and tell me what else you may need. Thank you

Comment: Could you `print("In setupNavBar() : self.navigationController =", self.navigationController)` at the beginning of `setupNavBar()`? and same for `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Yes I will but I’m currently having another error with my bridging header that won’t let me run the app so one I get that handled I will do that and let you know

Comment: You forgot to call super.viewWillAppear(animated:) in your overridden method. May that be causing your issue?

Comment: @CristianOrtega Unfortunately that didn't work